# JPQL query / JPA / Spring boot best practice of updating many to many table

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a `user` table and a `city` table and I have a connecting table `users_cities` (columns: id, user_id, city_id). A user can follow multiple cities. 
From the client side i send an array of `cityIds`. Some might be new some might still be selected and some might have been deselected.

What is a best practice to update the `users_cities` table with the data? Should I just delete everything for that particular `userId` and insert the new array or ... ?~

Also, how does one `delete` and repsectively `insert` the data in bulk, for a many to many reference?!

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    private Boolean isGuest;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_following_id")
    private Country countryFollowing;

    @ManyToMany()
    private Set<City> citiesFollowing;

    @ManyToMany()
    private Set<Offer> offersFollowing;

}
```

and

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NonNull
    private Long id;

    private String countryCode;
    private String name;

    @Latitude
    private Double latitude;
    @Longitude
    private Double longitude;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I just delete everything for that particular userId and insert the new array

Since the relation connecting users and cities does not have an identity of its own, that sounds reasonable

> Also, how does one delete and repsectively insert the data in bulk, for a many to many reference?

Just clear the `User.citiesFollowing` collection and populate it anew (hint: since you have `cityIds` at the ready, you can use `EntityManager.getReference()` to load the cities)